# redmine install fails , superclass mismatch for class SyntaxError

Tags: installation, redmine

I am trying to install redmine-2.4.1 but I recieve a superclass mismatch for class SyntaxError.  What could be the problem here?

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Rails 3.2.15

lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
Release:        5.4
Codename:       Final
```

```
    $ rake generate_secret_token --trace
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::ANY
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF8
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF16LE
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF16BE
    rake aborted!
    superclass mismatch for class SyntaxError
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/syntax_error.rb:5:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/syntax_error.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails.rb:10:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails.rb:10:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `'
    /opt/app/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /opt/app/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /opt/app/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `'


    $ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::ANY
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF8
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF16LE
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so: warning: already initialized constant Psych::Parser::UTF16BE
    rake aborted!
    superclass mismatch for class SyntaxError
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/syntax_error.rb:5:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/syntax_error.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/plugin.rb:1:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:3:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails.rb:10:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails.rb:10:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `'
    /opt/app/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /opt/app/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /opt/app/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `'
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you googled your problem?!

Look at it http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/36728

Author of the redmine issue was managed to fix a problem by adding `gem 'psych'` to Gemfile (and of course running `bundle install`). Try it - maybe it helps you

Comment: Google brought me here. The link you post ends with someone telling they found the solution on Google and giving an abrivated solution but I can't find their original page. Would have been nice to include a solution. Because this here is the first link I'm brought to when Googling. Something that tells me I should have Googled it.

Answer (score 1):

you should update rubygem and install bundle 1.17.3

```
gem update --system 
or
gem update --system 2.7.6 

gem install bundle -v 1.17.3
```